# In WebFocus, how to set average cell in total row?

Tags: average, webfocus

I am trying to create a report using WebFocus. This report has several rows and columns for different departments and their info. And at the bottom, there is one 'Total' row, which shows the summary for each columns.

Now my customers wants in the 'Total' row, one cell needs to show the average value of the column which it belongs to, which all the other cells keep the summary function.

I have no idea how to implement the change in WebFocus App Studio. Can anyone please guide me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way i can think of is, **UNION OF TWO TABLES**.
You can do it with **MORE** keyword in WebFocus.

With 'MORE' you can join 2 tables, 1 is your normal table and 2nd table is having customized columns For eg. first cell contains total addition of column cells, second column contains average or any other summary function.
i dont have working WebFocus right now, i will upload demo code soon.

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use: `ON TABLE SUMMARIZE AS 'TOTAL'`

This will summarize all values that are not computed and all computed fields will be wrapped and computed at the end, just like an average.